# for loop in flask python

Tags: python, flask

i have this simple for loop in flask framework

```
@app.route('/kde')
def fetch_erga():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT ergo FROM erga")
    rv = list(cur.fetchall())
    for row in rv:
        stock = str(row[0]['ergo'])
        tsapr += [(stock)]
    return '<h2>' + tsapr + '</h2>'
```

This leads to jinja crashing and producing the following error in the browser:
**KeyError: 0**

is it an error with key evaluation or the lack of it, or is it just bad looping?
Any help would be aprreciated

edit:
when running this:

```
@app.route('/kdef')
def fetch_ergas():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT ergo FROM erga")
    rv = list(cur.fetchall())
    return '<h2>' + str(rv) + '</h2>'
```

i get the following results in the browser

```
[{'ergo': u'52018'}, {'ergo': u'52019'}, {'ergo': u'63096700'}, {'ergo': u'68003400'}, {'ergo': u'68003501'}, {'ergo': u'69003501'}]
```

I mean it is not an empty cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KeyError is usually associated with a missing key in a dictionary. If it were me I would start looking into `str(row[0]['ergo'])`. Is it possible one of the row objects in `rv` does not have `'ergo'` key?

maybe if `cur.execute("SELECT ergo FROM erga")` returns an empty queryset?

EDIT:

every `row` in `rv` is a `dict` type object and you're referencing `row[0]` but there is no `0` key, change `stock = str(row[0]['ergo'])` to be `stock = str(row['ergo'])` and it should work

Comment: thx for your answer. running this: @app.route('/tyropitta')
def tyri():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT ergo from erga')
    rv = list(cur.fetchall()) #lista
    #return '<h1>' + str(rv[0]['ergo']) + '</h1>'
    return '<h1>' + str(rv) + '</h1>' gives me the following list  [{'ergo': u'52018'}, {'ergo': u'52019'}, {'ergo': u'63096700'}, {'ergo': u'68003400'}, {'ergo': u'68003501'}, {'ergo': u'69003501'}]. So the selection cursor is not empty...

Comment: `[{'ergo': u'52018'}, {'ergo': u'52019'}, {'ergo': u'63096700'}, {'ergo': u'68003400'}, {'ergo': u'68003501'}, {'ergo': u'69003501'}]`

Comment: `@app.route('/tyropitta')
def tyri():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT ergo from erga')
    rv = list(cur.fetchall()) #lista
    #return '<h1>' + str(rv[0]['ergo']) + '</h1>'
    return '<h1>' + str(rv) + '</h1>'`

Comment: try editing your question instead of commenting, its' not very legible

Comment: Worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use the template engine itself for this:
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#block-nesting-and-scope